# Unable to find explicit activity class {}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml Maps API not workingg ;( Java Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I have developed a simple app that allows users to login to a maps API and navigate around town.
I do not know why it is not working like this is the error,

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.vumaps/com.example.vu.MapActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

then in mainactivity I have this and nothing is wrong. The app launches, allows me to use log in screen then crashes after login. Do u know why it does not work? there are zero errors in code except for this one:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

//villanova university app dev

More codes

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, idkWhatToPutHere.MapActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you try to specify `MapActivity` in your manifest with the full package name `com.example.vu.MapActivity` instead of `.MapActivity`?

Comment: Are you sure this will work? I think I tried. I will tell you how it goes

Comment: Had the same problem. My activity was declared in the manifest, and nothing in my code had significantly changed.. 

I had to uninstall the app from the phone, clean the code, and deploy it again. 

Everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Your package name in the manifest is com.example.vumaps.  Your fully qualified class name is com.example.vu.MapActivity.  Using .MapActivity tells it to look for a class relative to the package name.  Since this doesn't match, it can't find the activity in the manifest.  To fix this, either rename the package of .MapActivity, or use the fully qualified name instead of .MapActivity.

Comment: Can u post a code snippets if possible. Very new to this